# How to Enable Edit access on locked records other than providing "modify all" access

Tags: permissions, access, contracts, edit

I have a requirement where some specific users need the edit permission on locked contracts (contracts currently under approval) for their market only. Those users are not Sys Admins, they cannot be given "Modify All" on contract because that will open up Modify access for other market records.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? Any other way other than providing "Modify All" on contract?

Comment: could they be added as an approver then? That would then allow you to set "administrators and current approver" as users who can edit the locked record.

Comment: I have not tried this but you create a screen flow that leveraged the [Apex Approval namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Approval_UnlockResult.htm#apex_class_Approval_UnlockResult), specifically the unlock and lock methods to temporarily allow for fields to be edited

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - currently approval process is sending the record to owner's manager for approval. the user who required the edit on locked record is other than the approver.